# Collection object is not callable. If you meant to call the createCollection method on a Database object it is failing because no such method exists

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I am having issues with mongoDB specifically when trying to create a collection.

I have imported pymongo and DNS they both work but when I try to create a collection using `db.createCollection("verified")`, it would throw an error saying that `'Database' not an attribute of 'createCollection'`

Here is the part of my code that involves MongoDB:

```
import pymongo
import dns

client = pymongo.MongoClient(myMongoDBconnectionURL)
db = client['MainDB']
db.createCollection("verified")
```

Do you know what is causing this?

Thanks

Comment: Please try to provide a running example. `myMongoDBconnectionURL` nor `db` are defined.

Comment: I realised I forgot to define db but even when I did, I get another error saying that Collection object is not callable. If you meant to call the createCollection method on a Database object it is failing because no such method exists

Comment: I read the pymongo documentation so I know createCollection is a method on db

Comment: You can always look at `help(db)` and `db.__dict__` to find information about what attributes and methods are available to you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect that you are using the wrong MongoDB Documentation (as in, the documentation of a MongoDB implementation in a different programming language). `createCollection` is not a method of `pymongo.database.Database`, but [`create_collection`](https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/pymongo/database.html?highlight=create_collection#pymongo.database.Database.create_collection) is:

```py
import pymongo
import dns

client = pymongo.MongoClient(myMongoDBconnectionURL)
db = client['MainDB']
db.create_collection("verified")
```

Comment: Also, it seems you can just do `db["verified"]`.